# Node app error when deploying on Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, deployment, server, ubuntu-14.04, elf

I've been developing a website using NodeJS, Express and MongoDB. The website works fine when I run it on my local machine. However, when I try to deploy it by running `node app.js` on an Ubuntu server instance(hosted by Vultr), I get the following error:

```
/home/appuser/UMISC_Website/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:119
        throw e;
        ^

Error: /home/appuser/UMISC_Website/node_modules/node-expat/build/Release/node_expat.node: invalid ELF header
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:779:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at bindings (/home/appuser/UMISC_Website/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/appuser/UMISC_Website/node_modules/node-expat/lib/node-expat.js:4:32)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:738:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/appuser/UMISC_Website/node_modules/xml2json/lib/xml2json.js:1:75)
```

Could someone please help me understand what I've done wrong?

Comment: What do `file -L /home/appuser/UMISC_Website/node_modules/node-expat/build/Release/node_expat.node` and `uname -a` produce?

Comment: @EmployedRussian `Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 bundle` and `Linux node-app 3.13.0-160-generic #210-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 18:08:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The website works fine when I run it on my local machine. However, when I try to deploy it by running node app.js on an Ubuntu server instance(hosted by Vultr), I get the following error:
>   `.../node_expat.node: invalid ELF header`

It looks like the server instance is using a 32-bit kernel, and you've tried to deploy a 64-bit `node_expat.node` binary to it.

**Update:**

> `file -L /home/appuser/UMISC_Website/node_modules/node-expat/build/Release/node_expat.node`
>   `Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 bundle`

My guess was close: you've deployed a 64-bit MacOS binary to Linux.

Linux doesn't understand / can't run MacOS binaries, so don't do that. You *must* replace the NodeJS with one built for your target OS (i.e. Linux x86_64 version).

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused- would I have to rebuild my node app from scratch on a linux machine, or is there anyway I could reconfigure it to run on Linux? (btw I managed to get a different node app to run on the Ubuntu server- that was developed on Mac as well)